# How can I add white space to the bottom of a page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know it's a really specific question, but I need to add 56px of white space to the bottom of a page using JavaScript - like the actual page is compressed so uses less screen space. Here are some images showing what I want to do (the white space is hard to see because it blends in with the background, but you can still see the actual website is smaller):

[image] [image]

I've tried using JavaScript to add in CSS to the page - using some different pieces of code for footers, but whatever I do, either the bar covers some of the page rather than moving the rest up or it just stays at the bottom rather than sticking when the user scrolls. For example this code:

```css
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui </p>

<div class="footer">
.
</div>
```

gives a rough idea of what I want, but unfortunately the website content goes behind it - for example when scrolling the text goes behind it. It depends on the size of the page on your screen, but on my display when I stop the example text at "qui" (like I have done in the example) the bottom of the "q"s are cut off:
[image]

I'd also like scrollling content to stop at the top of the white space rather than the bottom of the page. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to do this in your code, or some arbitrary website through developer console?

Comment: @CookieJarApps Please show the codes what you did, it will help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: @prakharlondhe it's for use in a WebView in an Android app so it has to be achieved in JavaScript and working on lots of different websites.

Comment: @Kevin I'll update the question in a minute with more details

Comment: @CookieJarApps If it is a webview then you can just shrink the size initially to whatever size you like, why do you require extra whitespace inside the webpage itself?

Comment: @prakharlondhe The webview has a toolbar that can move and unfortunately there is a bug where the layout doesn't work correctly - moving the toolbar gives a SigTrap error in the WebView which crashes the app and I have no idea why. This is a fix while I rewrite the app with a WebView alternative like GeckoView

Comment: @Kevin just updated it. I know there's only a small issue with my solution, but I've had users complain about a 1px gap at the top of a page so I'd rather have a solution that works perfectly. Also it's not JavaScript but I can just add the div and the styles in with a JS script so it's more the CSS and HTML that matter.

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y problem

Comment: @CookieJarApps Have you tried `body{ margin-bottom: 56px; }` ?

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for that comment by the way. I know it seems strange, but after that I decided to go back and have a look at fixing it in Kotlin and I actually managed to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add white spaces on the bottom of the page, I think the following would work:

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: white;
   text-align: center;
    height: 56px;
}

body{
    margin-bottom : 56px;
}
```

I tried it on w3schools tryit, and the following were the results

Before :

[image: Before[1]]

After :

[image: ][1]]

Answer (score 2):

using jquery sticky footer

```js
// Window load event used just in case window height is dependant upon images
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
       
       var footerHeight = 0,
           footerTop = 0,
           $footer = $("#footer");
           
       positionFooter();
       
       function positionFooter() {
       
                footerHeight = $footer.height();
                footerTop = ($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-footerHeight)+"px";
       
               if ( ($(document.body).height()+footerHeight) < $(window).height()) {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "absolute"
                   }).animate({
                        top: footerTop
                   })
               } else {
                   $footer.css({
                        position: "static"
                   })
               }
               
       }

       $(window)
               .scroll(positionFooter)
               .resize(positionFooter)
               
});
```

```css
#footer { background-color:#cccc;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc placerat, risus ut pretium pellentesque, quam neque finibus sapien, ac placerat ligula nibh et elit. Nunc malesuada dictum nunc. Nam fringilla, est eget sodales semper, nisi nibh aliquet sapien, vel viverra ex augue nec nulla. Sed et neque at ante aliquet ornare. Donec faucibus lorem nisl, non pellentesque leo vestibulum ac. Vestibulum et dapibus lorem. Proin tristique orci vel purus placerat, vitae porta dolor accumsan. Praesent ornare porta dolor id aliquet. Vivamus id rhoncus diam. Nulla a erat in nisl ullamcorper faucibus. Maecenas aliquam nulla quis arcu fringilla, sed convallis risus fermentum. Mauris a ex varius nulla porta euismod id at nisi. Etiam non dolor ac lacus luctus imperdiet. Nunc facilisis urna elit, ut dictum dolor condimentum in.</div>

<div id="footer">
    Footer
</div>
```